# I am trying to demodulate an OFDM signal

Tags: ofdm

I am trying to demodulate an OFDM signal which was captured using a spectrum analyzer.

The transmitted signal contained a 16 QAM modulation format, the received signal and the transmitted signal are not of the same length because the received signal is sampled for 20 periods, so to match the signal lengths I have performed a resampling in MATLAB.

FFT length is 487616, Cyclic prefix length is 36672, total signal length at the transmitter is 524288, the received signal has length 273068 ( hence the attempt to resample), the number of sub carriers used is 7619. The DAC sampling frequency is 48 GHz and the receiver sampling rate is 1.25 Gsps.

But when I try to demodulate the signal it gives me this messed up constellation diagram. I cannot figure out what is that I am doing wrong.

I am fairly new to OFDM signals.

[image: demodulated QAM constellation]

Comment: this doesn't really contain enough information! For example, how does your receiver know when to observe (== what is the method of time-synchronization)? How does your OFDM receiver work at all? you've literally told us nothing about your system! I think you'll have to describe it in way more depth, all of the following are missing but necessary: sampling rates, FFT lengths, Cyclic Prefix lengths (if any), synchronization methods

Comment: I am so sorry, I did not mention, FFT length is 487616, Cyclic prefix length is 36672, total signal length at the transmitter is 524288, the received signal has length 273068 ( hence the attempt to resample), the number of sub carriers used is 7619. About the time synchronization I do not know in details, I am sorry.

Comment: Could you please **edit** your question to include that info? You're still missing the sampling rates. Resampling because your *lengths* are different makes no sense - resampling because the rates are would.

Comment: I added the missing information, thank you for your suggestion, apologies for the inconvinience

Comment: what's the receiver's sampling rate?

Comment: It is 1.25 GSps